# Replacement window question: are newer windows a lot better then similar serviceable older double glazed windows? Northeast US

Tags: replacement

Friends mentioned that they are thinking of replacing their 30-40 year old double hung, double glazed two pane aluminum windows with similar style newer windows.
The old ones seem to be in good shape, there are no noticeable leaks, there is no condensation or any cracks in the glass, the springs and locks work and these are on the rear facade of their urban rowhouse.
It occurred to me considering that they are not swimming in money maybe one should ask if swapping  out these older basically modern well made windows for new ones would make financial sense. The outside aluminum clad wood stops keeping the windows from falling out clearly need recaulking or replacement.
Would love to hear from people who have been doing replacement/repair for decades what is their opinion. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As with most "new and improved" stuff, replacing for just because usually is a lot more cost, than the improve savings you receive.  Sealing any air leaks around the windows will be much cheaper and will probably increase heating savings much more.

Comment: This question is asking for opinions, but I believe it serves a good purpose, so I will not vote to close.   Often people make decisions based on their desire of mental comfort and sense of security.   I applaud you for looking after your neighbors.  From your description it sounds like the windows just need maintenance.  Try suggesting that to your neighbors along with the contact info of someone that can do the job for them.  You have then given them a reason to feel they have made the correct decision.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Indow Windows' website

> A single-pane window will have an R-value of 1. A standard double-pane window will have an R-value of 2. Some specialty windows that are highly insulated can reach an R-value of 5. This is great insulation, but the downside is the cost.

All of those are fairly miserable compared to the rest of the wall, but since you don't usually want to seal off the window that isn't a fair comparison.

Of course worn-out windows that don't seal well may leak air badly, which may be a bigger issue than single/double/gas-filled glazing. Repair may be a viable option.

Comment: Please add a link to the source of the quote.

Answer (score 1):

The major improvement .vs. 30-40 year old sealed double-pane windows is fancier internal coatings that limit solar gain and/or heat flow out. Fancier gas fill offers (purely temporary, to my understanding - it generally diffuses out over 5 years or so) higher insulation yet, at yet higher cost.

But the improvement over windows that don't otherwise need replacement (physically) is highly unlikely to pay back in operating cost savings. Windows are expensive, complex devices.

Replacing the old sealed units with new, fancier, sealed units (in the same frames, if those are in good shape) will generally cost less than complete new windows. It's still unlikely to pay off.

Comment: I think cars(gas to gas) are probably one of the very things where cost benefit will be worth it for just replacing reasons.